# How can I integrate authentication within .NET and Pentaho?

Tags: c#, vb.net, authentication, pentaho, integrate

I have tried to found example from internet about **integrate login authentication within .NET and Pentaho** but unluckily no solution found...

For example I have a web portal website need to login before use so that I have a customize login page let user to login the web portal:

After I input password and click Login button, the system will login to my web portal. The web portal include pentaho. that mean I no need to login Pentaho again if I already login web portal.

Now the question is [how can I authenticate within .NET and pentaho when I login?]

The successful scenario are:

1. When I click the link of Pentaho, the Built-in Pentaho login page will prompt me to   login if I do not click the Login button.
2. When I click the link of Pentaho, the Pentaho will **NOT** prompt login page after I click the Login button

May I know any example code or direction that help me to integrate login authentication within .NET and pentaho

Thanks in advance!